# I need to take answers of many participant attending and record answers but not working

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested-for-loop

#made a program but not working :(

```
num_ques=int(input('Enter Number of Questions: '))#take input number of questions
num_parts=int(input('Enter Number of Participants: '))#take input of number of person answering
n =1
m= 1
num_parts=int(num_parts)
part=[]

while num_parts>=m:
    while num_ques>=n:
        part.append(input(f'Enter Ans{n}: '))
        f=open('data1.txt','w')
        f.write(str(part))
        f.close()
        n=n+1
    m=m+1
```

***why the while loop is not running for all the number of participants,i.e num_parts>=m***

Comment: What do you think it doesn't run for all participants? I think the problem is that you're opening the file in write mode with w flag which is overwriting last written data and you need to open it in append mode using the a option.